# Hold viewing position when resizing a page with ratioed responsive divs

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a stack of 100% width divs that hold their shape/ratio when the browser window is resized. My problem is: if I've scrolled down to the bottom div (yellow in this example), then I resize the browser window, I end up looking at a different div because they're holding their ratio. Is there a way to stop this please?

http://jsfiddle.net/nWrVY/

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.wrapper:after {
    padding-top: 161.8%;
    display: block;
    content:'';
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper" style="background-color: red;"></div>
    <div class="wrapper" style="background-color: black;"></div>
    <div class="wrapper" style="background-color: green;"></div>
    <div class="wrapper" style="background-color: yellow;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'll have to say no unless 1- detect resize happened or 2- periodically reset focus periodically, which will be annoying,

Comment: I feel the same way, it is too much trouble to implement, and all that script probably out weight the benefit of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this in javascript with a few steps.

```
var current = "";

function scroll(){
// add 20 pixels to the scroll top so after we scrolled it does't fallback to the div before the one we're actually at.
    var scrolltop = $(document).scrollTop() + 20;
    $(".wrapper").each(function(){
// check if the offset of all divs is smaller than the scroll top
// the last one found is the last one visible
// save that one to a global variable so the resize function an access it
        if($(this).offset().top < scrolltop) current = $(this);
    })
}

function resize(){
// here we apply the top of the div to the body as scroll top 
   $("body").stop().animate({scrollTop:current.offset().top+"px"});
}

$(window).resize(resize);
$(document).scroll(scroll);
```

[EDIT] I amended the code to be more accurate (I added 20 pixels to the scroll top so the redefining of the current element does not redefine it as the element ABOVE it). This requires jQuery, so add

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To your  section and this should work, I tested it on the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks very much - I'm embarrassed to ask but could you help me implement it? Do I need to do more than this: http://jsfiddle.net/nWrVY/6/

Comment: See my edit, but just add jQuery to the page and use my amended script (I removed the variable in resize because, well, its only used once so use memory to store it?). Just beware that if you have many divs, it WILL slow down your page since it loops through the divs on every scroll event. Might be best to add a delay on the scroll function to only pull it a second after scroll has completed, aka `var scrolltime = false; function scroll(){ clearTimeout(scrolltime); scrolltime = setTimeout(function(){ /* current scroll function */ }, 1000); }`

Comment: Thanks for your time and patience! I have it working now - but it does get a bit erratic, scrolling automatically up to the top of the element above each element landed on. I'm starting to think the cost of this isn't worth it... thank you though!

Comment: Okay no problem :) just wondering (since I tested this code and it worked in testing), did it scroll to the wrong div? (I mean, if I got it wrong I;d rather know what went wrong!) Cheers

Comment: Ah - that last edit you made improved that bouncing a bit, thank you.

Comment: No, it's good - it's me: if you start from a view with 40% of the top element and 60% of the bottom, it'll scroll to the top of the top one - I hadn't understood that mechanic properly. Thanks!